# How to get call logs in android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentresolver

I am following this technique to get `call logs`, but i am getting messages details also with this.
Because `Samsung` has habit of *logging messages details* also as part of call logs.

```
String[] projection = new String[] {
                    CallLog.Calls._ID,
                    CallLog.Calls.NUMBER,
                    CallLog.Calls.DATE,
                    CallLog.Calls.DURATION,
                    CallLog.Calls.TYPE,
                    CallLog.Calls.NEW,
                    CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME,
                    CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_LABEL,
                    CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_TYPE
            };
            Cursor c =  mct.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC");`
```

Can any one tell me, how to filter only call details and exclude messages. This problem i notice espically in samsung phones

Comment: obviously you have to take a deeper look at `CallLog.Calls.TYPE` column

Comment: Yes, ` int callType = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE));` if i do like this, i'm getting this is of type incoming

Answer (score 0):

According to : `CallLog.Calls.Type`
The type of the call (`incoming`, `outgoing` or `missed`).

You wil filter by this tree types of call:

```
    int dircode = Integer.parseInt(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);     
        switch (dircode) {
        case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
            //dir = "OUTGOING";
            break;

        case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
            //dir = "INCOMING";
            break;

        case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
            //dir = "MISSED";
            break;
        }
```

Comment: Yes, but sometime i will be subscribed for call change event, suddenly i will get a sms, this will be treated as incoming call & it gets logged :(